# jquery - Select classes that follow without selecting all

Tags: jquery

I'm having a little issue selecting certain classes. In the example below, the first header has two "fontstyle" classes beneath it whilst the second header has one. This structure will end up being repeated with a different amount of fontstyle classes being applied each item (dynamic content editor)

I would like to be able to grab the each font style under each header and append it to the "content-wrapper". However, the issue I believe i'm going to have is that when attempting to grab the two fontstyle classes next to the first header, the other fontstyle class at the bottom will also be selected. Is there anyway around this?

Thanks all. Appreciate any help.

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="content-wrapper"></div>
</div >    
<div class="fontstyle"></div >
<div class="fontstyle"></div >

<div class="header">
    <div class="content-wrapper"></div>
</div >
<div  class="fontstyle"></div >
```

EDIT: Apologies all. I've updated the structure. I'm attempting to get the font style class into the content wrapper above it. This is the structure I would like at the end (for this scenario)

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
        <div class="fontstyle"></div >
        <div class="fontstyle"></div >
    </div>
</div >    


<div class="header">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
         <div  class="fontstyle"></div >
    </div>
</div >
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `+` selector. Then you can give the exact sibling pattern.

```
$(".header +.content-wrapper + .fontstyle")
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/J24yN/199/)

**Edit**

For updated question. Here you need to loop through each `.header` then find the `.fontstyle` elements until next `.header`. Then append that elements to the corresponding `.contentwraper`

```
$(".header").each(function () {
    var fontStyle = $(this).nextUntil(".header").filter(".fontstyle");
    $(this).find(".content-wrapper").append(fontStyle);
});
```

Comment: Thanks Anoop. I've had to update the structure quickly. My apologies for this.

Comment: Thanks for the response Anoop. Unfortunately that's not what I'm trying to achieve. I'm trying to append the fontstyles into their closest content wrapper. So in this example, the two font styles at the top will be appended into the first content wrapper, whilst the last fontstyle still be appended to the other.

Comment: @Tron can you elaborate more? which style you want to apply?

Comment: Hi Anoop. It's not about styling as such. It's about structure. I've updated the post to show the outcome that I would want. It's also worth bearing in mind that this structure will differ throughout the CMS that i'm using. Thanks for your time

Comment: Absolutely spot on! Thank you so much. :)